# Pandas groupby in combination with sklean preprocessing continued

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

Continue from this post:
[Pandas groupby in combination with sklearn preprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42772758/pandas-groupby-in-combination-with-sklearn-preprocessing)

I need to do preprocessing by scaling grouped data by two columns, somehow get some error for the second method

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import robust_scale,minmax_scale

df = pd.DataFrame( dict( id=list('AAAAABBBBB'),
                loc = (10,20,10,20,10,20,10,20,10,20),
                value=(0,10,10,20,100,100,200,30,40,100)))

df['new'] = df.groupby(['id','loc']).value.transform(lambda x:minmax_scale(x.astype(float) ))

df['new'] = df.groupby(['id','loc']).value.transform(lambda x:robust_scale(x ))
```

The second one give me error like this:

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[  0.  10.
>   100.]. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1)  if it contains a
>   single sample.

If I use reshape I got error like this:

> Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional

If I ever print out the grouped data, `g['value']` is pandas series.

```
for n, g in df.groupby(['id','loc']):
    print(type(g['value']))
```

Do you know what might cause it?

Thanks.

Comment: works fine for me. which version of pd,np are you using?

Comment: I'm using  Python 3.4.

Answer (score 3):

Base on the warning code , you should add `reshape` and `concatenate`

```
df.groupby(['id','loc']).value.transform(lambda x:np.concatenate(robust_scale(x.values.reshape(-1,1))))
Out[606]: 
0   -0.2
1   -1.0
2    0.0
3    1.0
4    1.8
5    0.0
6    1.0
7   -2.0
8   -1.0
9    0.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Why do I need to use concatenate? I think maybe I did not understand numpy at lower level very well.

Comment: @newleaf this output is array , if you do not do concat if will output object ,