# How to use sklearn preprocessor fit_transform with pandas.groupby.transform

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

How to use sklearn preprocessing fit.transform() with pandas.groupby.transform?

**I used this code here that works:**

[Picture of sample dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Gz7.png)

```
df.groupby('Category')['X1'].transform(lambda x: minmax_scale(x.astype(float)))
```

But when I changed it to the MinMaxScaler() method below, it returns error

**Code with Error when using .fit_transform method**

Assume the table only has 2 columns: Category and X1

```
df.groupby('Category')['X1'].transform(lambda x: MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(x.values.reshape(-1,1)))
```

**Error Message:**

> Data must be 1-dimensional

However, if I don't use the .values.reshape(-1,1) it will say

> Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead.
>   Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature

Are we not supposed to use the fit_transform method for .apply / .transform on pandas?

*Edit: updated with new error message*

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution, which is to wrap the scaler with np.concatenate()
Solution is similar to this thread here: [Pandas groupby in combination with sklean preprocessing continued](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54245551/pandas-groupby-in-combination-with-sklean-preprocessing-continued)

So the working code looks like this:

```
df.groupby('Category')['X1'].transform(
lambda x: np.concatenate(StandardScaler().fit_transform(x.values.reshape(-1,1))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You got to use MinMaxScaler object instance (add parenthses). Try this:

```
lambda x: MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(x.values.reshape(-1,1))
```

if you want to pass the scaling range, pass it to the constructor:

```
lambda x: MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 10)).fit_transform(x.values.reshape(-1,1))
```

here is a working example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame (np.random.randint(1,100,(10)),columns = ['a'])
df['a'].transform(lambda x: MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 10)).
                  fit_transform(x.values.reshape(-1,1)))

array([[ 0.        ],
       [ 6.55172414],
       [ 9.88505747],
       [ 6.09195402],
       [ 1.26436782],
       [ 8.62068966],
       [ 6.43678161],
       [ 5.74712644],
       [ 5.17241379],
       [10.        ]])
```

Comment: Yeah I forgot to put in the () after MinMaxScaler. But it still didn't work even with the (). If I didn't do the .values.reshape it will say 'Expected 2D array'. If I include the .values.reshape it says 'Data must be 1-dimensional'. Any thoughts?

Comment: I added a working example to the solution. Normally scaler applies to series without any `groupby`. With `groupby` one needs to use function that takes multiple values and returns single (like min, or mean or std). See manual for `groupby()`